# In Bravely Default, how do I delete a save file?

Tags: bravely-default

Simple question but I can't figure it out!

My copy of Bravely Default is pre-owned so has a save file on it which I want to delete. How do I do this?

(On a side note: any advantage to me keeping the other file? It's much further ahead in the game than I am, and at about level 65.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an arrow icon on the bottom right of the save file screen:

[image]

Click that and it should give you the option to delete files.

Answer (score 1):

From [gameFAQs forum post](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/729328-bravely-default/68169779):

> at the menu where you can see the three save slots - there's an arrow on the lower right of the screen. click on that to bring across options to copy/delete data.

If you decide to keep the save and finish the game, you can start new game+

When you start, you will be asked what you want to take over to the new game. Here is a list I found also on [gameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/3ds/729328-bravely-default/answers/366762-what-do-i-retain-in-new-game-)

- Character Names (If you've changed your character's names, which you can do from chapter 6 onwards I believe)
- Level
- Jobs available (So you could start a new game+ with all jobs available to use from the start if you have them all in your completed game)
- Job Level
- Funds (Pg amount)
- Items (Entire inventory, consumables, equipment, etc.)
- Genome Abilities
- Norende Village Population
- Norende Village Status (Completion status of the shops)
- D's Journal (Date revealed from the journal)
- Special Moves (Parts in place, names, set status)
- Play Time
- Friends
- Guests

You can check the box next to each one to mix and match with what you want to be transferred to your new game+